# Can i make horizontal scroll view that contains list of images to be like this?

Tags: java, android, listview

```
 <HorizontalScrollView  
                    layout_width="match_parent"
                    layout_height="wrap_parent">
    <listview       
    layout_width="match_parent"
    layout_height="wrap_parent"/>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

> I want the images that i'm getting from the API to be represented like
>   this image is that possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is android carousel. [This](https://github.com/mrleolink/SimpleInfiniteCarousel) sample will help you.
There is also [another](https://code.google.com/p/carousel-layout-android/) library which may be better for your needs.

Comment: It's close to what i want but not the same effect as the image above it shows one image per slide but thanks anyway.